# Remote loaded successfully but <module> could not be found! Verify that the name is correct in the Webpack configuration

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom

While using Module Federation plugin from webpack, I've connected two react applications and using dynamic url based import by using below

```
import { importRemote } from 'module-federation-import-remote';
```

remote url gets loaded in network tab but I see this error being shown by React Dom

[image: error in console]

I am using below to import remote app:

```
return importRemote({
    module: 'main',
    scope: 'campaign',
    bustRemoteEntryCache: true,
    remoteEntryFileName: 'campaign.js',
    version: 'some-version',
    url: 'https://localhost.corp.xyz.com:12398',
    remoteEntryFileName: 'campaign',
});
```

I expected remote application to be imported and running by module federation

Comment: Hi! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2):

Issue was due to webpacks splitChunks. changing optimization to below code resolved the issue

```
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: false,
  },
```